# Looking for a ghost short stories book

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a ghost book that had, "The Whistling Room," " The Monkey's Paw"  and I think, a story called, "Floral  Tribute."  It's a older book and I would like to know the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may be the anthology [*Shudders*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?361519) which contains "[The Monkey's Paw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey%27s_Paw)" by [W. W. Jacobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._W._Jacobs), "[The Whistling Room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnacki#%22The_Whistling_Room%22)" by [Wiliam Hope Hodgeson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Hope_Hodgson), and "Floral Tribute" by [Robert Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bloch).

I found this anthology by searching the [Internet Speculative Fiction Database](https://isfdb.org) (http://isfdb.org).

[image: Shudders anthology cover]

The full list of titles in this anthology is:

- A Forewarning (essay)
- Sweets to the Sweet
- The Waxwork
- Used Car
- The Ghost of Fear
- The Whistling Room
- The Last Drive
- The Monkey's Paw
- Second Night Out
- The Hills Beyond Furcy
- Floral Tribute

Comment: Yes!!!! That's it!! Thank you!!!!